How to make IPSEC connection between two end device using strongswan swanctl.conf?
I am new to strongswan v5.9.5 which uses swanctl.conf for making IPSEC connection. I am able to make LAN based IPSEC tunnel successfully. But my device which is a router which gets internet from LTE module which static IP address depends on SIM. My setup is like below-
My router(Device 1) --------------------------------My Ubuntu PC(Device 2)
LTE connection/cloud
My configuration for device 1(OpenWrt based) is-
secrets {
    
    ike-1 {
        id = "RTR"
        secret = "xxxx"
    }
}

connections {
    host-host {
        
    local_addrs = 192.168.2.1
        remote_addrs = x.x.x.x  
    
        
    local {
            auth = psk
        id = "@RTR"
        }

        remote {
            auth = psk  
        id = "@pc"
        }

        children {
            host-host {
                #local_ts = 0.0.0.0/0
                #remote_ts = 0.0.0.0/0
        remote_ts = 192.168.250.0/24
        updown = /usr/local/libexec/ipsec/_updown iptables
        rekey_time = 5400
                rekey_bytes = 500000000
                rekey_packets = 1000000
                start_action = start
        esp_proposals = aes128gcm128-x25519
        #esp_proposals = aes128gcm128-modp2048
            }
        }
    version = 2
      mobike = no
      reauth_time = 10800
    proposals = aes128-sha256-x25519
    #proposals = aes128-sha256-modp2048
    }
}


here in remote_addrs, I am putting static IP address through which device 2(ubuntu pc) is connected. Static IP address is given to my Microtik RTR where I have made port forwarding for 500 and 4500 ports for my Ubuntu PC IP.
But I am not able to get any response not even in Microtik Log. I anyone have any solution for the same.

Your local_addrs field is likely wrong, if you are connecting over the Internet, that either needs to be the public ip or a wildcard

I edited local_addrs = 0.0.0.0 , still not getting any response or any byte exchange between my board to Ubuntu PC

Ok , I got it after setting correct port forwarding in Microtik RTR, and slight changes in config both sides, it worked.
